# Exception NoClassDefFoundError JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping while upgrading Drill version to > 1.14.0

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, apache-drill

For our drill cluster, installed on Hadoop EMR core nodes, we use PAM based authentication. This is the below configuration.

```
security.user.auth: {
            enabled: true,
            packages += "org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security",
            impl: "pam4j",
            pam_profiles: [ "sudo", "login" ]
     }
```

We run our jobs through **YARN**, where the yarn application makes a **jdbc connection** to drillbits & produces the results. Drill+Yarn Jobs were working fine with 1.6.0.

We tried to upgrade our drill to *1.14.0* & greater, started seeing exception as below. A normal JDBC sqlline connection was fine though in all cases. Only the Yarn apps failing.

When the *'security.user.auth'* is disabled, Yarn jobs were fine.

**Exception**

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at oadd.org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:134)
> at oadd.org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.(Groups.java:79)
> at oadd.org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.(Groups.java:74)
> at oadd.org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:303)
> at oadd.org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
> at oadd.org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(UserGroupInformation.java:311)
> at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.security.plain.PlainFactory.createAndLoginUser(PlainFactory.java:63)
> at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.UserClient.prepareSaslHandshake(UserClient.java:452)
> at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.ConnectionMultiListener$HandshakeSendHandler.success(ConnectionMultiListener.java:160)
> ... 33 more
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at oadd.org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:132)
> ... 41 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oadd.org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping
> at oadd.org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:39)
> ... 46 more

**EMR Version 5.36.1**
Please let us know for any more info

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your trouble comes from the Hadoop native library. The version of that library installed by EMR 5.36.1 might not be compatible with the Java Hadoop libraries shipped with Drill. Check the Hadoop library version in your Drill installation with a command like this.

```
➜  ls /opt/apache-drill-1.20.3/jars/3rdparty/hadoop-common*.jar
/opt/apache-drill-1.20.3/jars/3rdparty/hadoop-common-3.2.4.jar
```

Finally, download a version of libhadoop.so corresponding to Drill's Hadoop library version found above and use techniques like LD_LIBRARY_PATH to ensure that Drill loads *it* and not the one that was installed by EMR.

Comment: The same exception happens for version 1.14.0, 1.16.0 of drill versions too. The Hadoop version was looking good with these versions

Comment: These versions of Drill are REALLY old.  We're currently on version 1.21.1.